# Did the Germans invent "Unexpected Pot-Shots"?

Tags: execution

I recently watched the TV-show "The Americans" where an execution scene was shown in a way that I have never seen before. The show is about spies during the cold war. In the scene the Russians deliver a death sentence and then immediately shoot the prisoner in the back of her head without her even realizing what was coming.

Today I read an article that said that the German Democratic Republic secretly performed "Unexpected Pot-Shots", similar to what can be seen on the show. It was considered to be more humane. However, I could not find any sources that say that other nations, for example Russia, did that too.

So my question is: Did the Germans invent that or did they steal it from somewhere? Maybe Russia? Are there reports about this execution method being performed before? Maybe by someone else?

In German that method is called "Unerwarteter Nahschuss" which literally would be something like "unexpected near shot".

Comment: Is the 'pot-shot' phrase yours or from another source? It really doesn't fit here. A 'pot' shot was a poorly aimed shot into a large crowd of targets, usually a large flock of fowl or pigeons, in order to fill the dinner pot.

Comment: If this actually happened then there would be some benefit of keeping the process a secret. After all, if it were widely known that you'd be shot immediately after the death sentence was given, it wouldn't be a surprise when it happened.

Comment: I used a dictionary to translate it. "Nahschuss" was translated as "potshot". The German version I took from a newspaper article. It reappears in several German newspapers.

Comment: I see. Must just be a difference in usage between the two languages then.

Comment: This same company doesn't make [Hungarian-English phrasebooks](http://www.montypython.net/scripts/phrasebk.php), does it?

Comment: Hmmm. It does seem to be a common translation I'm offered for that word. I'm guessing this is due to "potshot" generally meaning "random shooting". However, the randomness is meant to be more one of aim than of timing. I'd think taking a random unaimed shot at a prisoner would be a pretty ineffective method of execution (particularly in a crowded courtroom).

Comment: Honestly, the best word I can think of for this in English is "capping", but that's very urban-slangy (AAVE) and most dictionaries don't even have it.

Comment: It did not happen in a crowded courtroom. A few guards took her out of her cell without explaining, a guy sentenced her in only a few sentences and she was shot. Somewhere in a hallway.

Comment: The whole thing hardly deserves to be called "an invention". Likely multiple executioners came up with this due to both secrecy and obviousness. An early example could be Fanya Kaplan (died in Russia on September 3, 1918).

Comment: @doc: One should always check translations by a back-translation. here, English "potshot" translates to German "Schlagschuss", and English "pot shot" to German "Topfschuss". That suggests considerable error margin in **all** the automated translations. One really wants to find the English that translates to German "Nahschuss"; not the other way around.

Comment: I read something along this idea in Solzhenitsyn's The Gulag Archipelago: Officers escorting a delinquent/prisoner from the court room to a supposed cell, and shooting him while walking in the back of the head. The prisoner/delinquent hat no idea of an impending execution. It's been a long time, and I read it in the form of paperback. So, the search function is quite limited. Maybe someone with an eBook of it can find the exact pages.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there is going to be an authoritative "first" - after all, nobody is patenting this. Could have been independently "invented" multiple times & places.  If we remove the requirement for a gun, it could have been invented through most of history, and it converges to (possibly judicial) assassination.

Comment: [Et tu, Brute?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_tu,_Brute%3F)

Comment: As for the translation, "Nahschuss" is a "close shot". If you're going for something more figure-of-speech, you could go for "planted shot", but a Nahschuss does not have to be planted, so you're losing some precision of expression. "Potshot" is just wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/zeitgeschichte/todesstrafe-in-der-ddr-der-henker-kam-von-hinten-a-494202.html) mentions in an article from 2007:

> Danach wurden Verurteilte nach sowjetischem Vorbild mit einem "unerwarteten Nahschuss in den Hinterkopf" getötet: Beim Betreten des Hinrichtungsraums trat der Henker unvermittelt von hinten an den Verurteilten heran und gab ihm einen Genickschuss.

Translation:

> Afterwards, condemned were killed - as in the soviet model - with an "unexpected close shot in the back head" - : on entering the execution area, the executioner came abruptly from behind to the condemned and gave him a neck shot.

So it seems the Russians/Soviets were earlier,

Comment: Unless someone comes up with someone who did this before the Russians, I'll accept that answer. Missed the article. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider how the Soviet Union perpetrated the [Katyn Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyn_massacre):

> After the condemned individual's personal information was checked and
> approved, he was handcuffed and led to a cell insulated with stacks of
> sandbags along the walls, and a heavy, felt-lined door. The victim was
> told to kneel in the middle of the cell and was then approached from
> behind by the executioner and immediately shot in the back of the head
> or neck. The body was carried out through the opposite door and laid
> in one of the five or six waiting trucks, whereupon the next condemned
> was taken inside and subjected to the same treatment. In addition to
> muffling by the rough insulation in the execution cell, the pistol
> gunshots were masked by the operation of loud machines (perhaps fans)
> throughout the night.

That is, the Polish officer was unaware that they were being executed or had been sentenced; they were just killed, by an unexpected shot in the back of the head, in a systematic fashion. It does not appear that motivations for this sort of killing were for the sake of humanity; it was more a means to execute many people efficiently.

It appears that the massacre was performed under the supervision of [Vasily Blokhin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Blokhin):

> Blokhin initially decided on an ambitious quota of 300 executions per
> night, and engineered an efficient system in which the prisoners were
> individually led to a small antechamber — which had been painted red
> and was known as the "Leninist room" — for a brief and cursory
> positive identification, before being handcuffed and led into the
> execution room next door. The room was specially designed with padded
> walls for soundproofing, a sloping concrete floor with a drain and
> hose, and a log wall for the prisoners to stand against. Blokhin would
> stand waiting behind the door in his executioner garb: a leather
> butcher's apron, leather hat, and shoulder-length leather gloves.
> Then, without a hearing, the reading of a sentence or any other
> formalities, each prisoner was brought in and restrained by guards
> while Blokhin shot him once in the base of the skull with a German
> Walther Model 2 .25 ACP pistol. He had brought a briefcase
> full of his own Walther pistols, since he did not trust the
> reliability of the standard-issue Soviet TT-30 for the frequent, heavy
> use he intended. The use of a German pocket pistol, which was commonly
> carried by German police and intelligence agents, also provided
> plausible deniability of the executions if the bodies were discovered
> later.